# How to get Google sheet row id

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I would like to know if there is a way to get internal row id of a Google sheet, same way you have Worksheet name but it has unique worksheetId that does not change even if the name changes.

Can I get a row id that does not change even if the row number changes due to sorting, i.e something like a unique id used for internal reference of Google sheet rows.

Comment: Aside from the row number itself (which sounds like it won't work for you), the best way would be to have a unique value within the row contents to use as a key.

Comment: Why. I would like to see the use case. I am working on www.cellmaster.com.au and am interested in seeing use cases for things like this.

Comment: @Andy, that will work but what are the chances that between the time you used the custom row id to get the current row and column number that the spreadsheet has not changed?? 1. Get row and col number via custom row id. 2. someone sorts the sheet before your write completes. 3. you write based on row and column number collected at step 1. boom! record mismatch, unless there is something like spreadsheet lock so you lock and write then release lock

Answer (score 0):

### Not possible - Unique row id

While it is hard to be 100% sure, I have looked for this in both the spreadsheet API and google-apps-script. Nothing in the docs to suggests it exists. I have used both and have never seen a workaround.

### Ether Calc

A high quality open source spreadsheet very like google spreadsheets. Would be possible to change this. https://ethercalc.net/

Comment: Thanks a lot, even though due to deployment environment, i might not end up using Ether Calc, it is great too know there is an alternative. once again thanks.

Comment: so i checked Ether Calc and didn't see anything about reading and/or updating cell(s) value via row and column id not numbers.

Comment: @JideobiBenedineOfomah you are right. You you need to change it to allow updating by row/col id, so a few days work. I keep thinking of doing it, but don't have a pressing need.